# Click "hamburger menu" and open a side nav in React?

Tags: reactjs, class, toggle

I'm new to react. Trying to figure out how to bind a click event and make it toggle a class on two places. How do I achieve this?

Here's what I've done so far.

The nav:

```
import React from 'react';
import { css } from 'glamor';
import { container } from '../contents/grid'

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isToggled: true };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggled: !prevState.isToggled
        }));
    }

    showHeader() {
        this.refs.navigation.show();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <nav className={nav} {...container}>
                <ul {...hamburger} className={this.state.isToggled ? "" : "active"} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
```

And the side menu/header:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { css } from 'glamor';
import { header, nav, navUL } from '../contents/navigation';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    show() {
        this.setState({
            isToggled: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header {...header}>
                <nav {...nav}>
                    <ul {...navUL} className={styleUl}>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/'>Robin Savemark</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/experience'>Erfarenhet</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/education'>Utbildning</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/project'>Projekt</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/knowledge'>Kunskaper</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to='/contact'>Kontakt</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        )
    }
}
```

And the App where I only render each component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Header from './Header';
import Main from './Main';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navigation />
                <Header ref="Navigation" />
                <Main />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How do I tell my "handleClick" method to "toggle" the hamburger menu and the header/side-menu? Because the handleClick is inside another scope (Navigation) and I wan't it to do the same inside the Header class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two components to share the same event / state, you need to do what the react docs refer to as **lifting state up**

You can structure it however you please, but right now, your `App.js` is holding your two components of interest but has no `state` of its own. Therefore, there's no way these two components can share state. What you want to do is have an event handler within `App.js` that you then pass down to the component(s) of interest as a prop, as well as have a `toggle` class contained within its own state.

Once you trigger the `function` passed down to `Navigation`, it will tell `App.js` "hey, I just did this thing you told me to do, you handle it from here." `App.js` will say "okay, updating the state for myself so both you and `Header` can get what you need." `App.js` will toggle its state, and pass that as a prop down to both `Header` and `Navigation`.

React doc reference here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up